# Getting Room Data using Intent Extras with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-room

I am new to Couroutines, viewmodels and Room. I am building an app with 2 activities that stores Hymns, HymnList and HymnContent activities respectively.

1. The first activity displays data on a recyclerview, presented on cardviews (hymn_title, hymn_number and hymn_language.
2. The second activity is supposed to display the content (hymn_text) of the selected items from the cardviews.

It looks like this:

[image]

I am a little confused on how to pass the intent extras... I have implemented a listener on the Adapter passing the position of the selected item, but I need some help on how to get that exact item from Room on the Second Activity.

Here is my intent:
[image]

And here's the View Model

```
    class HymnViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
        private val repository:HymnRepository
    
        val allHymns: LiveData<List<Data>>
        init {
            val hymnDao = HymnDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).hymnDatabaseDao()
            repository = HymnRepository(hymnDao)
            allHymns =repository.allhymns
        }
    
    
        fun insert(data: Data) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
        repository.insert(data)
        }
    }
```

The Dao is here:

```
    @Dao
    interface HymnDatabaseDao {
        @Query ("SELECT * FROM data")
        fun getAllHymns():LiveData<List<Data>>
    
        @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
        suspend fun insert(hymn: Data)
    
        @Query("DELETE FROM data")
        suspend fun deleteAll()
    }
```

And here's the Activity that should display the contents (Second Activity)

```
    class HymnContentActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        private var hymnPosition = POSITION_NOT_SET
        private lateinit var hymnViewModel: HymnViewModel
        
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_hymn_content)
    
            hymnPosition = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_HYMN_POSITION, POSITION_NOT_SET)
            if(hymnPosition!= POSITION_NOT_SET) {
                displayHymn()
            }
   
        }
    
        private fun displayHymn(){
            //get hymn corresponding to position
            //val hymnText: TextView = findViewById(R.id.hymn_display_text_view)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    
        }
    }
```

The Repository is here (Included after the first answer was suggested):

```
        class HymnRepository(private val hymnDatabaseDao: HymnDatabaseDao) {

        val allhymns: LiveData<List<Data>> = hymnDatabaseDao.getAllHymns()
        suspend fun insert(data: Data){
            insert(data)
        }
        suspend fun getHymnById(hymnId:Int):Data{
            return getHymnById(hymnId)
        }
    }
```

I will be glad if some pro could help.
Regards!

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of hymn position use hymn number, or what is the primary key for `Data` class that is returned by your `HymnDatabaseDao`. Pass into extras the primary key of the selected hymn;
2. Add new function in your DAO interface (and repository) to get a single hymn by its primary key;
3. Add new `getHymnById` method into your view model;
4. In receiver activity query a specific hymn by given primary key.

First step. Using hymn number/id instead of hymn position.

```
inner class HymnViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    ...
    var hymnId: Int = -1 // -1 will be considered invalid ID

    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(it.context, HymnContentActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_HYMN_ID, hymnId)
            it.context.startActivity (intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Second step: add new function to DAO interface. Update your repository accordingly.

```
@Dao
interface HymnDatabaseDao {
    ...
    
    @Query ("SELECT * FROM data WHERE hymnId = :hymnIdArgument") //hymnId is column name of the primary key
    suspend fun getHymnById(hymnIdArgument: Int): Data
}
```

Third step: view model is updated with the new method used to extract a single hymn.

```
class HymnViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val repository: HymnRepository

    ...

    suspend fun getHymnById(hymnId: Int): Data {
        return repository.getHymnById(hymnId)
    }
}
```

Fourth step: query a specific hymn and display its data as you wish.

```
class HymnContentActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        private val INVALID_ID = -1
    }

    private var hymnId = INVALID_ID
    private lateinit var hymnViewModel: HymnViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hymn_content)

        hymnId = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_HYMN_ID, INVALID_ID)
        if (hymnId != INVALID_ID) {
            getHymn()
        }
    }

    private fun getHymn() {
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            val hymn = hymnViewModel.getHymnById(hymnId)
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                displayHymn(hymn)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun displayHymn(hymn: Data){
        val hymnText: TextView = findViewById(R.id.hymn_display_text_view)
        hymnText.text = hymn.hymnContent
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Jenea. 
It worked for me. However, I think the code in my repository might be having an issue? Kindly inspect if it is correct..
I have added the code of the repo as an edit to the question...

Comment: @ManzuGerald, I got acquainted with the repository. Cannot spot any issues.